# Find the down host in zookeeper

Tags: python-3.x, apache-zookeeper

```
from kazoo.client import KazooClient
from kazoo.client import KazooState
zk =KazooClient(hosts='172.30.63.168:2181,172.30.63.169:2181,172.30.63.170:2181')
zk.start()
```

**In my case i want to find the server which is down using python**
The above program contains 3 hosts.one of the host in 3 host down i want to find that server.and also find the leader host from this 3 hosts.
Achieve  this tasks using python(kazoo) or some other modules in python

Answer (score 2):

Kazoo library seeems not exposing an API to detect the leader of the cluster. But you may use the zookeeper commands srvr, isro etc. to know which is the leader and in general, if you cannot connect to a zookeeper-server, that sever may very well be down (assuming they are not behind some firewalls from the clients you are running). 
The leader will be in rw mode (read-write mode), while the followers in ro mode. You may use this to check who is the leader. Below is a sample Python program that may help:

```
import socket
'''
    leader_takes an array of (host, port) tuples and returns leader, array-of-followers,
    array-of-down-hosts
'''
def leader_detect(hostports):
    sk = None
    leader = None
    followers = []
    down = []
    for hp in hostports:
        sk = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            sk.connect(hp)
            sk.send(b'isro')
            resp = sk.recv(1024)
            if resp == r'rw':
                leader = hp
            else:
                followers.append(hp)

        except Exception as e:
            down.append(hp)
        if sk:
            sk.close()
    return leader, followers, down

## Sample run....
leader, followers, downs = leader_detect([('zk-serveer1-host', 2181), ('zkserver-2-host', 2181)])
print 'leader: {}, followers:{}, downs: {}'.format(leader, followers, downs)
```